# How do we best deal with public remote calls in lightning desktop?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

Testing out existing Visualforce pages in Lightning desktop we're coming across a lot of javascript errors around the remote calls to our controllers:

> Javascript proxies were not generated for controller
>   namespace.SomeController: may not use public remoted methods inside an
>   iframe.

I have found [this resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_scope_visibility.htm) which says we can simply change our classes and remote methods to global. However it also states:

> Globally-exposed remote actions shouldn’t perform sensitive operations
>   or expose non-public data.

Any suggestions how to best resolve this issue in Lightning Desktop without having to change a bunch of classes and methods to be global?

Thanks
Nelson

Comment: I'm curious why the warning about global access control on a method. You still need to have a valid Salesforce session Id. I may see if I can get someone to comment on this that may know.

Comment: Further investigation I found this was not a bug. It worked in Lightning. The problem (where the error was found) was that we were rewriting the url and sforce.one.navigateToUrl(doggy_url) was opening a new iFrame and the error was occurring.